# Java access an array element from another class I created

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, static

I am creating an array in the class with main method

```
Word attempts = new Word (26);
```

Field in class Word is

```
private String [] attempts;
```

Constructor in class Word is

```
public Word (int a){
        attempts = new String [a];
        create(attempts);
    }
```

Where create is a method that makes every array element an empty String `("")`. In class Word I've also got a `getAttempts()` method for accessing the attempts array. Now, I want to make class Letter where i pass the before created array `Word []` in a for loop. I tried with Word.getAttempts()[i], but I get an error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getAttempts() from the type Word`. To my understanding when a method is static, you do not have to create an object before calling the method. I have no idea how to pass the array created in Main method to this Letter class. Any help?

edit: Here is my Word class

```
public class Word {

private String [] attempts;

public String[] getAttempts() {
    return attempts;
}

public void create (String [] attempts){
    for (int i=0; i<attempts.length; i++){
        attempts[i]="";
    }
}

public Word (int a){
    attempts = new String [a];
    create(attempts);
    }
}
```

To sum up, I am creating an array in class with Main method that is type of Word, and I want to pass that array to separate class Letter.

Comment: the message says that your method isn't static ... please  insert your class

Comment: @André Edited the post, how about now?

Answer (score 2):

```
Word.getAttempts()
```

... would be how you would access a static method named `getAttempts` in class `Word`. However, your method `getAttempts` is not static: it works on instances of your class.

Assuming you define such an instance as follows:

```
Word word = new Word(26);
```

Then, provided the method is public, you can access the array with:

```
String[] attempts = word.getAttempts();
```

> To my understanding when a method is static, you do not have to create an object before calling the method.

Yes, but your method is not static.

---

> I understand that, but after defining Word array in Main method, how can i access it in a new class?

You pass objects through methods or constructors, which allow other objects to interact with it using the API defined by public methods.

> Now, I want to make class Letter where i pass the [...] array

Define a class named `Letter`, and a constructor which accept an object of class `Word`.

```
class Letter
{
    private final Word word;
    public Letter (Word word) {
        this.word = word;
    }
}
```

And in `main`:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Word word = new Word(26) ;
    Letter letter = new Letter(word);
}
```

You could pass directly `word.getAttempts()`, but then you are directly working with the internal values of another class, which is bad style. Better work with instances of `Word` through its public methods than by directly accessing its private data.

Comment: I understand that, but after defining Word array in Main method, how can i access it in a new class?